# Validating the "select" dropdown before submitting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

On my page, there can be numerous select dropdown which need to be validated in certain way before I submit the page.

As an example, on a certain instance, there can be seven select dropdowns as follows.

What I want is that:-

> if there are 5 or more "selects", exactly one should have 1 selected, exactly
>   one should have 2, exactly one should have 3 and so on till 5.
>   Remaining all of them should have 0 selected automatically.

and

> if there are less than 5, exactly one should 1 selected, exactly one
>   should have 2 selected and so forth till 4. This would depend upon how
>   many "selects" are present on the page

What I did is below in JS. It's basically not much helpful :-(

### HTML

```
<select name="first_select_0" class="select_style">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<select name="first_select_1" class="select_style">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<select name="first_select_2" class="select_style">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<select name="first_select_3" class="select_style">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<select name="first_select_4" class="select_style">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<select name="first_select_5" class="select_style">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<select name="first_select_6" class="select_style">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

### JS

```
$("#submit-selection").click(function(e){
        var count_selects = $(".select_style").length;
        if (count_selects >=5 ) {
            alert(count_selects + "is >=5");
        }
        else {
            alert(count_selects + "is <5");
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

### My JsFiddle is

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/8wcp6/1/)

Comment: can you please create jsFiddle?

Comment: Would you explain once more :) Like, `if there are 5 selects, at least 4 options from 2 selects should be chosen`; `if there is only 1 select, at least 3 options should be chosen`... 'cause I can't exactly figure out the rules.

Comment: Here is one I wrote 10 years ago: http://plungjan.name/SO/selectUnique1.html

Comment: Hi Hex, basically, I want only unique values to be selected. If the selects are more than the options, then rest of them get a Zero. Have a look at JsFiddle, I selected the way it should be.

Comment: Hi mplungjan, Unfortunately this is not what I want. In my case all selects have same options. There are six options in total with each select. All I want is that each select has unique option selected. If the selects are more than six, every extra one should be assigned a zero.

Comment: In my case all the selects have the same options. When you select one, the selected option becomes unavailable to the other selects

Comment: Nonetheless, it is quite brilliant :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
$(function() {

    $("#submit-selection").click(function(e) {

        var selects = $(".select_style");

        var option_occurrences = {0:0, 1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0};

        for (var i = 0; i < selects.length; i ++) {
            option_occurrences[selects[i].value] ++;
        }

        var ok = true;

        for (var i = 1; i <= Math.min(5, selects.length); i ++) {
            if (option_occurrences[i] != 1) {
                ok = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        alert(ok ? "OK!" : "not OK...");

        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

[Online Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8wcp6/2/)

Comment: Aww... Thank you (all) :3

Answer (score 1):

If I understood what you want, this should work:

```
function validate(){
    passed = true;
    if ($('select').length > 6) {
        for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            if (i > 0) {
                if ($('select option:selected[value=' + i + ']').length != 1) {
                    passed = false;
                }
            } else {
                if ($('select option:selected[value=' + i + ']').length != 2) {
                    passed = false;
                }
            }
        }
        if (passed) {
            alert('passed');
        } else {
            alert('not passed');
        }
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < $('select').length; i++) {

            if ($('select option:selected[value=' + i + ']').length != 1) {
                passed = false;
            }

        }
        if (passed) {
            alert('passed');
        } else {
            alert('not passed');
        }
    }
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4hcgH/1/).

Comment: Hi Walid, Thank you for taking out the time for this but unfortunately this is not behaving as expected. d0c just submitted another option which works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. I hope it will solve your problems... :)

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit-selection").click(function(e){
        var count_selects = $(".select_style").length;
        var select = $('#form1').find('select');
        var track = [];
        var limit = 0;
        if (count_selects >=5 ) {
            $.each(select, function(i, v) {
                var val = $(this).val();
                if(val != '0')
                    track.push(val);
            });
            limit = count_selects - 1;
        }
        else {
            $.each(select, function(i, v) {
                var val = $(this).val();
                if(val != '0')
                    track.push(val);
            });
            limit = count_selects + 1;
        }
        if(checkArray(track , limit) == 1){
            //alert('here');
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
function checkArray(track, limit){
    var flag = 0;
    for(var i = 1; i < limit; i++)
    {
        if($.inArray(i.toString(), track) == -1){
            alert('Can\'t submit');
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
</script>
```